# Polynomial-time algorithm to generate the "opposite" of a binary Gray code?

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory, gray-code

I'm seeking to implement a function $\phi(n,k,i)$ of integers $n,k,i$ where $$1 \leq k < n\\1 \leq i \leq N\\N = {n \choose k}$$ that returns all possible $n$-element binary vectors containing $k$ $1$'s, in sequence, with $i$ specifying the index of the element to return. Additionally, the elements (words) of the sequence must be ordered in such a way that every word differs "as much as possible" from all prior words in terms of Hamming distance.

That is, letting the words of the sequence be $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_N$ with $$w_i = \phi(n,k,i)$$ and $d(w_1,w_2)$ be the Hamming distance between $w_1$ and $w_2$, I'd like to maximize a function $$J = \sum _{i = 2}^{N} D(i)$$ over the order of the words in the sequence, where $D(i)$ is a rough measure of the distance of the $i$'th word from all its predecessors, such as $$D(i) = \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} d(w_i,w_j)$$ or perhaps a fancier weighted-by-recency version such as $$D(i) = \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} d(w_i,w_j)\; r^{i-1-j}$$ for $0 < r < 1$.

I don't want to define "rough measure" more rigorously than this since any $D$ that yields values positively correlating to either of the above is also fine--the stronger the correlation, the better.

In a sense, I'm looking for the "opposite" of a binary Gray code (wherein successive words are designed to resemble their nearest predecessors as much as possible).

The motivation is to generate the sequence in a deterministic way so that when $\phi$ is queried to return the first $p$ words of the sequence, with $p$ typically being $\ll N$, the set of words is always diverse. In actuality, the words represent bit masks for the $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set. Like creating $p$ dishes where $k$ ingredients are selected for each dish from a common pool of $n$, such that the diversity in combinations of ingredients is as high as possible even if $p$ is small.

Finally, while I know this problem can be brute-forced by evaluating $J$ for each one of the $2^N$ possible word orderings, $N$ will typically be $> 1000$, ruling this out as a practical option. An algorithm for implementing $\phi$ with $O(N^2)$--or ideally $O(N \log N)$, $O(N)$, or better--time and memory requirements is ultimately what I'm looking for.

It seems to me that with all the mathematical and computer science research going on out there, *somebody* must have come up with some ideas on this.

Comment: Related: [“Anti-Gray codes" that maximize the number of bits that change at each step](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315544/anti-gray-codes-that-maximize-the-number-of-bits-that-change-at-each-step)

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm linked to in the comments takes the $n-$ bit standard Gray code, appends a 0 to the left and then uses complementation to every other pattern in order to obtain maximal change in consecutive words. This would seem to address your requirements.

Donald Knuth's Pre-Fascicle 2A, available [here](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc2a.pdf) discusses a number of different gray code algorithms and introduces the idea of a *delta sequence* which can be used for efficient generation of the next Gray codeword.

Comment: An added complication is that only words with a specific weight (number of $1$'s) can be used in my application, which isn't the case for the anti-Gray code in MJD's link. Furthermore, while each word's distance to its predecessor (and near odd-numbered predecessors) is large, its distance to near even-numbered predecessors is small. I'm looking to maximize the sum total difference over all predecessors, especially when $p$ is small. Obviously, by the time $p$ is anywhere close to $N$, word order matters little.